# Mount .NRG image file on OSX 10.6

Tags: snow-leopard, mount, dvd

I have a Nero Disk Image(.nrg) File and I would like to mount it on OSX to copy it's contents. I've tried to rename to .iso and to use NRG2ISO with no luck.

Any tips ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little googling led me to this thread on **[MacRumors.com](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=276016)**

It appears that if the ISO is a single session CD image you can just knock the first 600 bytes off with a terminal command and it'll be readable as an ISO (change file type to .iso after performing the command).

**I'd recommend making a backup of the .nrg file before trying this though!**

```
$ dd if=image.nrg of=cdrom.iso bs=512 skip=600
```

(↑ credit to balamw on macrumors forums)

Also, If you're just looking to extract pictures from the disk, [File Juicer](http://echoone.com/filejuicer/) may also be **[worth a look!](http://echoone.com/filejuicer/formats/formats?f=nrg)**

Comment: Thank you for the tip, but this didn't work for me :( (when I mount the resulting iso I get 'not recognized')

Comment: dd just reads the in file (if) so it's not writing to the nrg file in this case.

Comment: `bs=512 skip=600` skips the first 307,200 (512 x 600) bytes, not just 600.

Answer (score 4):

Had the same experience as the OP. Tried using nrg2iso, tried renaming the file to .iso and also tried the `dd` command from that MacRumors thread. Nothing worked.

However, I then found [nrg4iso](http://code.google.com/p/nrg4iso/) which worked perfectly! The project has been abandoned since 2007 but it still works.

Comment: I tried `nrg4iso`, but it erred with the following message: "Source is a Nero DAO (Disc at once) image with 2 session(s)."

Answer (score 4):

dd variant not work for me. So, i find another one with poweriso:

http://www.poweriso.com/download.php

Use:
./poweriso convert ~/Desktop/image.nrg -o ~/Desktop/image.iso -ot iso

Answer (score 0):

With *.nrg* images from audio CDs, the solutions proposed in the other answers do not work (e.g. failing with *Source is a Nero DAO (Disk at once) with 1 session(s)* ).

However, the commercial [Deamon Tools](http://www.daemon-tools.cc/) are now available [for Mac OSX](http://www.daemon-tools.cc/products/dtMacLite). Using these, you can mount the *.nrg* as an Audio CD.

Answer (score 0):

There are not many options on Mac for this purpose. I think [AnyToISO](https://www.crystalidea.com/anytoiso) is good freemium choice. Its freemium version supports up to 870 MB.

[image]